# Automatically logout user after a specified time of inactivity

Tags: java, wicket, httpsession

I am using java and wicket in my web application. Basically i would like to automatically logout the user in code after a specified time of inactivity. For example lets say that the time is a setting in my application. I have already looked into HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(600). But setting this value is making the session expired and the webpage still remains idle. I am not sure about the code to automatically logout user and redirect to login page.

Comment: Client needs to initiate the redirect somehow. For example, start a timer (in JavaScript) that is reset with every user action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior with slightly bigger duration to initiate a call to the server. If the session is expired Wicket IAuthenticationStrategy will automatically redirect to the login page.